# Svelte custom store doesn't accept local variables

Tags: forms, validation, store, svelte, yup

I am trying to build something similar to Formik using yup, every function works, except of the function that validates the form.

I'm using the latest version of svelte (not the alpha).

```js
const createFormik = () => {
    const { subscribe, set, update } = writable({
        values: {},
        validationSchema: {},
        errors: {}
    });

    const validate = () => {
        let newErrors = {};
        update(object => {
            object.validationSchema.validate(object.values, { abortEarly: false })
                .catch(errors => {
                    errors.inner.forEach(error => {
                        newErrors = {...newErrors, [error.path]: error.errors }
                    });
                });
            return {...object, errors: newErrors};
        })
    }

    return {
        subscribe,
        update,
        setInitialValues: (initialValues) => update(n => ({ ...n, values: initialValues })),
        setValidationSchema: (validationSchema) => update(n => ({ ...n, validationSchema: validationSchema })),
        setErrors: (errors) => update(n => ({ ...n, errors: errors })),
        validateSchema: () => validate(),
        updateFieldValue: (name, value) => update(n => ({ ...n, values: { ...n.values, [name]: value } }))
    }
}
```

Instead of updating the errors object in the store with the matched errors, the update returns empty errors object.

Comment: Does `validate(...)` return a promise? Based on the `.catch`, it looks like it does — in which case your `errors.inner.forEach` code is running *after* the new object has been returned. You probably need to validate *then* call the `update` function (which calls its argument synchronously)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Rich Harris said the problem was, I used promise inside the update function.
Updating after the promise or inside the promise solved it.

```js
const createFormik = () => {
    const { subscribe, set, update } = writable({
        values: {},
        validationSchema: {},
        errors: {}
    });

    const validate = (object) => {
        let newErrors = {};
        object.validationSchema.validate(object.values, { abortEarly: false })
            .catch(errors => {
                errors.inner.forEach(error => {
                    newErrors = { ...newErrors, [error.path]: error.errors }
                });
                console.log(object);
                update(n => ({ ...n, errors: newErrors }));
            });
        update(n => ({...n, errors: {}}));
    }

    return {
        subscribe,
        update,
        setInitialValues: (initialValues) => update(n => ({ ...n, values: initialValues })),
        setValidationSchema: (validationSchema) => update(n => ({ ...n, validationSchema: validationSchema })),
        setErrors: (errors) => update(n => ({ ...n, errors: errors })),
        validateSchema: (object) => validate(object),
        updateFieldValue: (name, value) => update(n => ({ ...n, values: { ...n.values, [name]: value } }))
    }
}
```